# ffmpeg batch command to reduce file quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, jpeg

I've got a directory with thousands of images (png, jpg, bmp, etc.) and thousands of videos (mp4, mpv, mpeg, etc.).

The png images may be ~10 MB and I can open them one at a time in GIMP, reduce quality from 100% down to 92% and the image size goes down to ~2MB and the quality (to the eye) hardly changes.

How can I do this process in bulk (ie batch) to everything (pics and video) in the directory using ffmpeg? And how do I overwrite everything in the directory so I don't have duplicates?

Are there any GUI tools for such a thing? Maybe it's better to stick with the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a `for` loop as below

```
for f in *
   do 
     extension="${f##*.}"
     filename="${f%.*}"
     ffmpeg -i "$f" -q:v 1 "$filename"_lq."$extension"
     rm -f "$f"
   done
```

By increasing the number `-q:v 1` the quality will be more reduced.

Comment: that works, Thanks. Do you mind adding two more "solutions" in your answer? **(1)** How do I make your for loop recursive? In other words how do I apply the same operations to all images/video within folders within the directory I'm working out of? **(2)** How do I prevent non-image or non-video files from getting deleted in your for loop? Things such as text files are getting deleted when I run this for loop as is. Finally, it would be awesome if all three solutions were contained in individual code chunks. That'll help me understand, and hopefully others who eventually read this.

Comment: 1) need to use `find` instead of for loop. better to know what formats (.jpg,.png,.mkv,...) we are going to deal with. 2) if we know the file extensions then the code only searches for those files not ALL of them.

Comment: I ended up using the following command to move all files from sub-solders to their parent folder: `find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv {} . \;`. And I'm very aware _now_ that any non image or video files will be deleted with this loop. This solves my issue. Thank you.